# Flutter packages path not found

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've installed Flutter without Android Studio following these two tutorials: https://medium.com/@quicky316/install-flutter-sdk-on-windows-without-android-studio-102fdf567ce4 and https://dev.to/ejgamer21/install-flutter-without-android-studio-58bi.
I have connected my phone with USB debugging enabled and I've run `flutter doctor`: everything seems to be fine (although I haven't configured an IDE yet). Then I've tried to run the "Hello world" example that comes with Flutter using `flutter run` in the *hello_world* directory, but I get this error:

```
lib/main.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/b/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/widgets.dart': Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato.
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
       ^
lib/main.dart:12:16: Error: Method not found: 'Key'.
          key: Key('title'),
               ^^^
lib/main.dart:13:26: Error: Getter not found: 'TextDirection'.
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:11:9: Error: Method not found: 'Text'.
        Text('Hello, world!',
        ^^^^
lib/main.dart:9:11: Error: Method not found: 'Center'.
    const Center(
          ^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:8:3: Error: Method not found: 'runApp'.
  runApp(
  ^^^^^^
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\mpepi\Android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\mpepi\Android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 4s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         4,7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

("Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato" means "Couldn't find the specified path")
Something seems to be wrong with the path for the packages, I have located the required file at `C:\Users\mpepi\Android\flutter\packages\flutter\lib` which of course is different from the one in the first line. I have set all environment variables as the tutorials explain, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete in the .vscode file. Restart the flutter application of visual studio code and run 'Flutter run'. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't installed VSCode yet but I thought the 'flutter run' command should have worked anyway. Now that I have installed VSCode and set it up properly, I've successfully run the Flutter demo app!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set "File Transfer" mode on your phone, it usually is on the notification bar if the phone is conected

Answer (score 0):

For some cases I've also faced the similar issue. This problem is likely to arise *when flutter doesn't get the packages*. It wasn't even getting the `material` package, like your `widget` package.

**Fix**: Go to `pubspec.yaml` file. Make sure your internet connection is on and working. If you're developing in vscode you'll find buttons at top-right corner. Click `Get Packages` and wait until flutter downloads the packages.

If you don't find those buttons, then [from the command line navigate to the project folder](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/change-directories-command-prompt-windows-10-11) and run `flutter pub get` or `flutter packages get`.